# Scala class - convert to java

Tags: scala

I am converting below scala code into java using javap command. getting some weired thing in the output.

```
scala>class Order(var id:Int)
scala> :javap -p Order
Compiled from "<console>"
public class $line19.$read$$iw$$iw$Order {
  private int id;
  public int id();
  public void id_$eq(int);
  public $line19.$read$$iw$$iw$Order(int);
}

scala>
```

getting $line19,$ symbol in javap output. is it expected one. ? do i need to do anything

Comment: Its nothing wrong.

Comment: How can  i suppress this weird string. Any idea

Comment: Umm.... I guess you can try to write another Scala compiler.

Comment: You can remove this weird line by hand, or try to decompile an object defined not in the console, but in a file. Anyway, `$read$$iw$$iw$Order` is a valid Java identifier, and that's what this `Order` class defined in the console is calles internally.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is to be expected.

The Scala REPL allows you to re-defined `val`s, for example, which is not allowed in Scala. The way this is implemented, is that every line you enter into the REPL is wrapped in an object, so that every line is in a separate namespace. What you see there in the de-compiled output is that object which is generated by the Scala REPL.